# Custom dialog with multiple checkboxes

Tags: java, android

I'm going to create an alert dialog with multiple checkboxes that rows are right to left.I mean the checkboxes place at the right of each rows and I be able to change text color and other things...
So how can I do that?
this is my code.But all the directions are left to right.

```
    Dialog dialog;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.choose_your_category));
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectedItemId, boolean isSelected) {
                    if (isSelected) {
                        posarray.add(selectedItemId);
                    } else if (posarray.contains(selectedItemId)) {
                        posarray.remove(Integer.valueOf(selectedItemId));
                    }
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //Your logic when OK button is clicked.
                    for (int i = 0; i < posarray.size(); i++) {

                        int position = posarray.get(i);
                        idarray.add(catarrayList.get(position).getCategoryId());
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });
    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Try meterial alertdialog git cpde to get meterial design with alert box

Comment: you can create a layout for Alert Dialogue and there you can write any custom design you want